# Checkinstall doesn't install package globally

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, ffmpeg, checkinstall

I am trying to compile `ffmpeg` from sources and create `deb` package in order to install ffmpeg globally and make it possible to remove it with `dpkg -r` command.

Here are my commands.

```
# Installing FFmpeg
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=ffmpeg --pkgversion="5:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no \
  --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default
hash -r
```

Everything compiles successfully, deb packages are created but when I try to use `ffmpeg` I get

```
ffmpeg: command not found
```

So that means that `ffmpeg` still not installed in `$PATH` directories.

What is wrong with my commands?

Comment: Where did you find the instruction to install this way?

Comment: do `whereis ffmpeg` to get its current location

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: And used checkinstall in order make this package available globally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial you mentioned does not use `checkinstall` because nothing is installed to the system: it "locally installs" the compiled binaries in the `~/bin` directory of the user performing the compiling. It does this for a variety of reasons: avoids the complexities of the package management system, avoids messing with system directories, makes updating compiled `ffmpeg` easier, for shared server users it avoids root/superuser (assuming dependencies are available), and avoids conflicts with the *ffmpeg* package in the official repository.

Some methods to make your compiled `ffmpeg` globally executable for all users:

## Move it to `/usr/local/bin`

This is easy:

```
sudo mv ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffplay} /usr/local/bin
```

Downside is that it won't be integrated into the package management system, but that shouldn't be a big deal since undoing this is simple.

To "uninstall":

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffplay}
```

## Use `checkinstall`

If you want to use `checkinstall` to install the compiled `ffmpeg` binary for integration into the package management system, and so any user can execute it:

```
cd ~/bin
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=ffmpeg --pkgversion="8:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --default install -Dm755 ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

This assumes the `ffmpeg` binary is in `~/bin` which it will be if you properly followed the tutorial.

Alternatively, you could remove `--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"` and `--bindir="$HOME/bin"` when configuring `ffmpeg`, then run `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make`, and finally run your `checkinstall` command from your question if you want to install everything else (libraries, documentation, `ffplay`, `ffprobe`) too instead of just the `ffmpeg` binary.

Comment: I followed these instructions (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) and I am still not 100% clear on how to tell checkinstall which folder to add to the PATH (I compiled BRLCAD 7.28 with `./configure && make && sudo checkinstall` and the final bin dir ended up `/usr/brlcad/dev-7.28.0/bin/`)

Comment: @nmz787 I recommend asking that as a new question.

Comment: it seems no different than the OP's "So that means that ffmpeg still not installed in $PATH directories." which is true

Comment: @nmz787 The OP followed a guide that "installs" the FFmpeg executable files to `~/bin` on purpose for reasons already mentioned above. All that the `checkinstall` command does in the answer is install it to `/usr/local/bin` for the sole purposes to 1) integrate it into the package management system, and 2) to make `ffmpeg` accessible to all users as requested by the OP. This is a roundabout way of doing things because they could have just compiled without the custom `--prefix` and `--extra-*` options then run `checkinstall` normally.

Comment: @nmz787 Trying to use `checkinstall` to fix BRLCAD's oddball prefix seems like an XY Problem. I know nothing of BRLCAD or why it is installing to `/usr/brlcad/dev-7.28.0/bin/`, but using `checkinstall` to change this is not the right tool for the job, as it should be done via the `configure`/`cmake` step. That's why I suggested you ask a new question.

Comment: ah, I see, you didn't mention changing the `./configure` options, are those standard (I see `--bindir="$HOME/bin"` in the OP)? If so, please add to your answer :)

Comment: @nmz787 Using `--bindir="$HOME/bin"` is not "standard". It is used in the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for specific reasons unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, i was creating deb package for git 2.18

commands:

cd git_2.18.1 (tar extracted folder)
./configure --bindir=/usr/local/bin && make
sudo checkinstall

The package  git_2.18.1-1_amd64.deb was created whos  install path is /usr/local/bin